# Format negative milliseconds

Tags: python, time

I have a function which converts milliseconds to h:m:s.ms format and it works.

However I have one problem and it is about negative numbers.

the code

```
def timer(ms):
    s = ms / 1000
    m, s = divmod(s, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    #d,h = divmod(h,24)
    d = ms % 1000

    if h > 0:
        return "{0}:{1}:{2}.{3}".format(int(h), str(int(m)).zfill(2), str(int(s)).zfill(2), str(int(d)).zfill(3))
    elif m > 0:
        return "{0}:{1}.{2}".format(int(m), str(int(s)).zfill(2), str(int(d)).zfill(3))
    else:
        return "{0}.{1}".format(int(s), str(int(d)).zfill(3))


print(timer(13700)) 

# returns 13.700 as expected
```

-

When I give a negative miliseconds for example -13700

```
print(timer(-13700))
```

it returns

```
59:46.300
```

but the expected output I want is **-13.700**

How can I solve this?

Comment: Remove the `-` sign to convert to a positive integer, run it through your function, then prepend the `-` sign again to the result?

Comment: Perhaps convert to positive, then add the negative sign at the end?  Will you also have a problem with zero?

Comment: That cant work Danielle as i have a lot of data and need to know which ones have negative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to detect negative inputs, get their absolute values, and then put `-` on the front when you return them:

```
def timer(ms):
    if ms < 0:
        return "-" + timer(abs(ms))
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A good approach to cleanly solve this would be:

1. determine the sign
2. use the absolute value (abs) for arithmetic
3. add the sign back to the output

So modifying your code would look like:

```
def timer(ms):
    sign = ms//abs(ms) if ms != 0 else 0 # <---  Step 1
    ms = abs(ms)                         # <---  Step 2
    s = ...
    ...        
    if sign == -1:                       # <---  Step 3
       output = "-"+output
    return output
```